# Two different layout for site ezpublish

Tags: ezpublish

I am using ezpublish 5.x legacy version. Currently my site is using same page layout for all the pages.

Now based on a particular content class i want to show entirely different page layout. Is it possible?

It is not possible with template overriding as zones in the new page layout will be entirely different.

Comment: Are you running entirely in legacy mode? This is possible in both the new stack and the old stack, we just need a little more information before providing a proper response.

Comment: Yes, i am running entirely in legacy mode.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by it not being possible because of zones, are you using eZ Flow and want to change the layout based on whether or not a certain content type is added to the eZ Flow zones?

Answer (score 2):

This should be possible using the standard override options provided by eZ Publish. In your `override.ini`, add a new block for the override:

```
[layout_custom_class]
Source=pagelayout.tpl
MatchFile=pagelayout_custom_class.tpl
Subdir=templates
Match[class_identifier]=custom_class
```